# indexing nested dictionary elements

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I am trying to access the  dictionary elements in python, which looks like this:

```
mydict= {'message':'','result':[{'abc':1,'xyz':2}]}
```

I want to access the value of key `'xyz'`.Is there any direct method to access it in python.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Direct access? You mean `mydict['result'][0]['xyz']`?

Comment: @Sebastian Probably without knowing the intermediary keys.

Comment: that was quick...Thanks @Sebastian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In steps,

- `mydict['result']` returns `[{'abc':1,'xyz':2}]`
- `mydict['result'][0]` returns `{'abc':1,'xyz':2}`
- `mydict['result'][0]['xyz']` returns `2`

Answer (score 0):

The answer above is wrong in that mydict['result'][0] doesn't work because you don't index dictionaries like a list.

To access 1, you must use the actual string in the key of the nested dictionary:  mydict['result']['abc']